# Is it possible to create a Mac OS X gui app which is not a bundle?

Tags: macos, user-interface

I want to make an executable file (not the Mac `.app` bundle) which when run with a specific option (e.g. `-gui`) will pop up the gui.

For example, say I'm writing `wget`. I could do: `wget www.google.com` and that would print the result to the console, but if I instead do: `wget -gui www.google.com` that would pop up a gui window with the render of the html.

Is this possible in OS X (it is in windows)?

Note: I mean that the gui code is contained in the executable, calling `open` on another app is not acceptable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple: Yes

Your second question will be how I guess.

Sometimes people ask me for applications that when launched by the Finder they should behave normal but when started by another process or terminal it should behave different. So, just like firefox, you can start the application the normal way or you can start it with special option.

Another way is creating agents. They are applications but don't appear in the dock and are designed to show interface elements when needed.

If you don't want to use a bundle per se you can just create a (cocoa) command line utility that loads an NSApplication when needed (depending on the command line options).